# How can I run a code with multiples functions?

Tags: python, function

```
def Km(x):
    return x*1.609344
#km and miles
operation = input('example : (km to miles)\n')
if operation in ['km to miles','KM TO MILES']:
    f = float(input('Your distance in km :'))
    a = Km(f)
    print('\n miles =')
    print(float(a)/1.609344**2)
elif operation in ['miles to km' ,'Miles to Km', 'miles to km']:
    f = float(input('Your distance in miles :'))
    a = Km(f)
    print('\n km =')
    print(float(a))

restart = input('Press enter to convert again . ')

if restart in [' ','','   ']:
    main()
```

How can use mutliple functions without having an error ?
or is there a better way to loop my code back .

Comment: Of course you can use multiple functions without having an error. Which error do you have?

Comment: One problem is you try to call "main" but that function was never defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im trying to loop loop my code back

Comment: Error : expected an indented block after function definition on line 2